# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS 4 using dispatch_once, not in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4, grand-central-dispatch

I'm guessing this must be new functionality as this code fail on my iOS4 device, works fine on iOS5. I need this to work on both. I haven't moved to iOS5 yet as I still need to support iOS4, so I'm at a loss as how to workaround this ?

```
static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{ //EXC_BAD_ACCESS
   _sharedStoreManager = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];            
});
```

It's from https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/blob/master/MKStoreManager.m

Comment: `dispatch_once` is available on iOS 4.0 and later. Can you provide more information about the crash?

Comment: Can you show us your backtrace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dispatch_once()` is not new with iOS 5.0, it's been around since 4.0. I use it all the time in applications that target 4.0, such as in this singleton from one of my frameworks:

```
+ (GPUImageOpenGLESContext *)sharedImageProcessingOpenGLESContext;
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static GPUImageOpenGLESContext *sharedImageProcessingOpenGLESContext = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedImageProcessingOpenGLESContext = [[GPUImageOpenGLESContext alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedImageProcessingOpenGLESContext;
}
```

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_once):

> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

I'm guessing your problem exists within the `-init` of your _sharedStoreManager. For example, is there a reason why you are using `-allocWithZone:` there?

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by a bug in my code, and I have pushed a fix for it. Update your submodules. Thanks to Brad Larson for notifying me.

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch_once` [is available](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW13), and there's nothing wrong with the snippet you've posted.

I see two problems with the rest of the code, however, both stemming from line 194. First, the manager is being sent `init` twice: once inside the `dispatch_once` Block, and then after, on that line:

```
if(!_sharedStoreManager) {
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedStoreManager = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];            
    });

  #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    NSLog(@"You are running in Simulator MKStoreKit runs only on devices");
  #else
/*194*/_sharedStoreManager = [[self alloc] init];
```

This is a bad thing to do.

Causing that, and more important, though, is that this looks like an infinite loop. Line 194 there calls `+[MKStoreManager alloc]`, which will end up at `+[MKStoreManager allocWithZone:]`, which calls `+sharedManager` again!

```
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{   
    return [self sharedManager];
}
```

I wouldn't have thought that such a loop would cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but I recommend removing line 194; it's incorrect.

(I'd also recommend fixing the indentation of the `if` block.)